# angular $resource post, creating a repo in github using github api

Tags: angularjs, curl, resources, github-api

From github api documentation

Create a new repository for the authenticated user.

POST /user/repos
Create a new repository in this organization. The authenticated user must be a member of the specified organization.

POST /orgs/:org/repos
OAuth scope requirements

When using OAuth, authorizations must include:

public_repo scope or repo scope to create a public repository
repo scope to create a private repository

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -d    '{"name":":test-repo"}' https://api.github.com/orgs/test-org/repos
```

Using the curl command, it works fine, but how do we replicate that in angular using the $resource service with post method.
Below is what i have, and i get a "bad credentials error" even if i use the same token using curl and successfully created a repo in the organization, "test-org". If i include the access token in the header like 
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;    charset=UTF-8', access_token:'xxxxxx....xxxx'},
then i get a CORS error.
ps: access_token....the 40 chars personal access token & the person is a member of the org, "test-org"
For get method, it works fine as expected but the problem is with post method.

```
var headers = {}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;    
charset=UTF-8'},
var access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
var factory = $resource('https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos',
            {
               org:'test-org',callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
               access_token:access_token}, {
                create: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {
                     name: 'test-repo', 
                     description: 'this is blabla'},
                     headers: headers
                    },
                get: {
                     method: 'JSONP',
                     headers: headers
                }
            }
            );

        return factory;
```